# How to restrict one user account to only two devices

Tags: node.js, angular, operating-system, saas

These days I am working on a web SAAS product in which I want that user who will subscribe to my service can use their account from only two devices. So how can I restrict the user account to two devices only?

Can I use MAC address for it? Like if I ask for two MAC addresses at the time of registration and check the current MAC address at the time of login or is there any more secure way of it?

If I will ask for my users MAC addresses then will it be secure for their privacy?

I’m using **nodeJS** for backend and **angular** for frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it based on currently active sessions for a user. so that even if user login from two different browsers from same device, after that he couldn't login from third browser. But if you want it to be device based, first you should take acceptance from user to pickup information like their MAC address to avoid infringement of privacy. plus this is totally backend driven.

Comment: Lets suppose if I store MAC addresses of users in my database and due to any loopholes that database has been hacked. Can hackers access the devices data using those mac addresses only?

Comment: Nope, hackers shouldn't be able to. Atleast as far as i know. But you should secure this data as effectively and efficiently as possible via encryption etc or try something like fingerprint js. As leakage of this information will impose penalty and legal complications under GDPR compliance or other law depending on region in which your app is operating. Plus before deciding to pick this information, make sure that you have valid reason, permission of it in law where your app will operate, and also acceptance by user.